# Why is my code skipping this line

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This code is creating an inventory for an RPG game. I'm calling the item information from Items database that is a `json` file. For some reasons it is skipping this line. I marked it in the code to make it stand out a little more.

```
data.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = data.amount.ToString();
```

here is the entire code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

ItemDataBase database;
GameObject inventoryPanel;
GameObject slotPanel;
public GameObject inventorySlot;
public GameObject inventoryItem;

int slotAmount;
public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
public List<GameObject> slots = new List<GameObject>();

private void Start()
{
    database = GetComponent<ItemDataBase>();

    slotAmount = 20;
    inventoryPanel = GameObject.Find("Inventory Panel");
    slotPanel = inventoryPanel.transform.FindChild("Slot Panel").gameObject;
    for (int i = 0; i < slotAmount; i++)
    {
        items.Add(new Item());
        // and empty slot
        slots.Add(Instantiate(inventorySlot));
        //set parent to slot panel
        slots[i].transform.SetParent(slotPanel.transform);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
        items[i].ID = -1;
    }

        AddItem(0);
    AddItem(1);
    AddItem(1);
    Debug.Log(items[1].Title); 
}

public void AddItem(int id)
{


    Item itemToAdd = database.FetchItemByID(id);

    if (itemToAdd.Stackable && checkIfItemIsInInventory(itemToAdd))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].ID == id)
            {
                ItemData data = slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<ItemData>();
                data.amount++;
                **data.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text =      data.amount.ToString();**
                 break;
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            // in video had this set to -1
            if (items[i].ID == -1)
            {
                items[i] = itemToAdd;
                GameObject itemObj = Instantiate(inventoryItem);
                itemObj.transform.SetParent(slots[i].transform);
                itemObj.transform.position = Vector2.zero;
                itemObj.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = itemToAdd.Sprite;
                itemObj.name = itemToAdd.Title;
                itemObj.name = itemToAdd.Title;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool checkIfItemIsInInventory(Item item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (items[i].ID == item.ID)
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "skipping this line"? Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to see what is exactly going on?

Comment: Yes I have and it goes to data.amount++; then jumps to other parts of the program that don't have anything to do with this section. skips the     **data.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text =          data.amount.ToString();**

Comment: and the break;

sorry cant edit post yet so I have to just make another

Comment: Have you checked that no part of `data.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>()` is null?

Comment: what is `data.amount`? If its a property then its normal that code might jump around as you are calling the getter and specially the setter which in turn can trigger all kind of stuff seemingly unrelated to the code you are worried about. Have you actually followed it all the way through and verified that it never comes back or when it does that it skips the line you've highlighted? Also, is this a multithreaded application and more than one thread is hitting your breakpoint(s)?

Comment: here is the code for the data.amount. Don't know how to make it in code form in the comment section really sorry about that.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemData : MonoBehaviour {

    public Item item;
    public int amount;
}

Comment: Ensure that the debugger is configured to stop on exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some debugging information. First here is the whole function it is messing up on

```
 public void AddItem(int id)
{


    Item itemToAdd = database.FetchItemByID(id);

    if (itemToAdd.Stackable && checkIfItemIsInInventory(itemToAdd))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].ID == id)
            {
                ItemData data = slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<ItemData>();
                data.amount++;
                data.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = data.amount.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

so when I get to this line while debugging

```
  data.amount++;
```

the watch says
data ---- null
data.amount ---- Could not find the member 'amount' for 'object'
amount---- the identifier 'amount'is not in the scope

so to break all of this down data is initialized here 
    ItemData data = slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent();

amount is here (this is a different file called ItemData
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

```
public class ItemData : MonoBehaviour {

public Item item;
public int amount;
}
```

thanks everyone for being helpful I really just want to learn how to code better.

Comment: after data.amount++ excutes it jumps out of all the loops and goes to checking if the player is in a box next to an enemy. so something completely different and not even called in this area.

Comment: from reading your new post, it looks like `data` is `null` or `data.amount` is `null`.  Please verify that in the debugger.   So an exception (a run-time error) is probably being thrown, which does not return you to the next line of execution.  The exception is probably handled somewhere else, then execution continues on from that new location.  If `data.amount` is `null`, replace that whole line with `data.amount = (data.amount ?? 0) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a break point at the block above:

```
if (items[i].ID == id){
```

or even higher at:

```
if (itemToAdd.Stackable && checkIfItemIsInInventory(itemToAdd)){
```

Step through (using F10) and see if it's hitting the line.  It's probably jumping out when one of the conditions aren't met.  That, or if you need to execute this line through the entirety of the `for` loop, it's jumping out of the loop when it hits the line the first time because of the `break;` following.

Either way, step through the lines after the break point, and check the values of everything.  Make sure you're not getting `null` references or values.

Comment: I have debugged the program multiple times. it gets to the line right above it in the for loop then just exits out never even goes to the break line to wait for me to press the key to exucte break;

Comment: If it never enters the `for` loop, either `items.Count` doesn't have a value, or if it skips the block entirely, it means that `if (itemToAdd.Stackable && checkIfItemIsInInventory(itemToAdd))` returned false.

Comment: @bobsmith - do you how to place a break point in your code?  (Not to be confused with the line you have `break;`.)  I know you said you're new to this, so I just want to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: yes I break point is set in side the for loop that is inside the `if (itemToAdd.Stackable && checkIfItemIsInInventory(itemToAdd))` it enters into that for loop like it is supposed to do and I press f11 to excute `ItemData data = slots[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<ItemData>();`. Then the arrow goes to the line `data.amount++;` and when I press f11 there it jumps out to another spot in the enemy movement which is never even called. `data.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = data.amount.ToString();` and ' break;' never get excuted